# Possible dynamic programming to solve selection between price and stores

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am doing a course project and encounter the following problem.

Given shops (A, B, C), products (1, 2, 3), and their price as (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3), the number of shops the customer wants to visit and the total amount cash that the customer has. Provide the solution that the customer can get all the goods at the cheapest price.

I was thinking of using dynamic programming to solve this problem because it seems that the problem itself is a subset of smaller problems but I have no idea of how to accomplish it. Pleas help!

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  Do you have any particular programming language in mind or already in use? Have you made any attempt at a possible solution?

Comment: It is a side project I am working on, I am working on the javascript since it is a web app. The attempt that I have made so far is to use the brute force for this solution but the performance is okay when number of shops is below 7. As a result, I am researching and try to find a better algorithm for this problem.